# Conditional update and select statements in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a schedule table in postgresql. I want the user to be able to update any columns in a row. If the user only changes one value I want that value to be updated and all of the other values remain the same as they are in the database. I've tried doing a straight update statement and any undefined inputs would change the column value to null.

Here's my solution far

```
create table schedule (
    id serial primary key,
    instructor_id integer references users(id),
    holidays boolean, 
    sunday_morning text,
    sunday_afternoon text,
    monday_morning text,
    monday_afternoon text,
    tuesday_morning text,
    tuesday_afternoon text,
    wednesday_morning text,
    wednesday_afternoon text,
    thursday_morning text,
    thursday_afternoon text,
    friday_morning text,
    friday_afternoon text,
    saturday_morning text,
    saturday_afternoon text
);
```

INSERT STATEMENT

```
insert into schedule (
    instructor_id,
    holidays, 
    sunday_morning,
    sunday_afternoon,
    monday_morning,
    monday_afternoon,
    tuesday_morning,
    tuesday_afternoon,
    wednesday_morning,
    wednesday_afternoon,
    thursday_morning,
    thursday_afternoon,
    friday_morning,
    friday_afternoon,
    saturday_morning,
    saturday_afternoon
) values (2, false, null, '7 - 9', null, null, '4 - 7', null, null, null, '9 - 11', null, null, null, null, null )
```

UPDATE STATEMENT

```
update schedule 
set 
    holidays = case when true <> NULL then true else holidays end ,
    sunday_morning = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else sunday_morning end,
    sunday_afternoon = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else sunday_afternoon end,
    monday_morning = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else monday_morning end,
    monday_afternoon = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else monday_afternoon end,
    tuesday_morning = case WHEN 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else tuesday_morning end,
    tuesday_afternoon = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else tuesday_afternoon end,
    wednesday_morning = case WHEN 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else wednesday_morning end,
    wednesday_afternoon = case when 'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else wednesday_afternoon end,
    thursday_morning = case when 'asd' <> NULL then  'asd' else thursday_morning end,
    thursday_afternoon = case when  'asd' <> NULL then 'asd' else thursday_afternoon end,
    friday_morning = case when  'asd' <> NULL then  'asd' else friday_morning end,
    friday_afternoon = case when  'asd' <> NULL then  'asd' else friday_afternoon end,
    saturday_morning = case when  'asd' <> NULL then  'asd' else saturday_morning end,
    saturday_afternoon = case when  'asd' <> NULL then  'asd' else saturday_afternoon end
where instructor_id = 1
select * from schedule
```

asd is just dummy data. I can't figure out why it breaks. 
I tried it on a smaller scale and it worked perfectly, however now it throws an error.

Comment: what does the error you get?

Comment: just tried it again and didn't get an error, but it didn't update any of the values

Comment: according to your insert query everything is ok, because you've inserted a row with `instructor_id = 2`, but try to update a row with `instructor_id = 1`

Comment: Moreover `'asd' <> NULL` is always false, when comparing to `null` values you have to use `'asd' is not null`, same with `true <> NULL` - it is always false

Comment: didn't update ):

Comment: it will not update anything, because each `case when` expression will produce `false` value

Comment: just tried this `holidays = case when true IS NULL then true else holidays end,` no luck

Comment: true is not equal to null :)
Null will always be equal to null only. Read this manual about working with null it will help you to understand what is wrong with your query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: `sunday_morning = case when 'asd' IS NULL then sunday_morning else 'asd' end,` this didn't work either.